# How to fit a one-dimensional dataset with respect to several bounded parameters?

Tags: fitting, chemistry

I have this set of data

```
mydata={{1244,0.90237},{1289,0.83072},{1306,0.76147},{1360,0.6094},{1388,0.40952},{1428,0.29419},{1488,0.15592},{1494,0.11718},{1527,0.09192},{1537,0.07757},{1590,0.04546},{1594,0.04563},{1654,0.03229},{1737,0.01976},{1740,0.01949};
```

and I need it fitted into a function of the form

```
Exp[-(A*TT*^n*Exp[-Ea/(R*TT)])*t]
```

where $R$ is the gas constant $R=8.31\dots$ and $t=0.002$. This is a decay and the function in the exponent is the [Arrhenius factor](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Arrhenius_equation).

I checked the help for the fitting tools, but what I found was either in one variable, or in more variables, but for a higher dimensional plot. I also have variable bounds which I need to implement. I have this simple curve with parameters

```
A, n, Ea
```

$A$ is bounded by $10^{12}$ and $10^{14}$, $Ea$ lies between $270000$ and $320000$, $n$ close to zero (single digit). The plot of the function should be with respect to temperature $TT$ is the varying variable on the x-axis.

Comment: You need `NonlinearModelFit`. Do not use capital letters as variables names. There are couple of built it. `N` `C` `I`

Comment: It might be more convenient to work with the `Log` of your data.

Comment: @Kuba: Thanks for the hint. I tried the NonlinearModelFit and it worked but the values I get are far off. How can I implement the boundaries?

Comment: You can implement boundaries with `{Exp[-(a*tt^n*Exp[-ea/(r*tt)])*t], 10^12 <= a <= 10^14, 0.5 < n < 10, 
 270000 <= ea <= 320000}` (or similar with the log version) within `NonlinearModelFit`.

Comment: Are you trying to use the Arrhenius equation with a temperature-dependent pre-exponential factor?  If so then you need to look at your exponential: R is in $J\ mol^{-1}\ K^{-1}$, TT is unitless so your activation energy, Ea is in the same units as the gas law constant.

Answer (score 5):

Only `NMinimize` method can be used for constrained problems.

```
{r,t}={8.31,0.002};

data={{1244,0.90237},{1289,0.83072},{1306,0.76147},{1360,0.6094},{1388,0.40952},
{1428,0.29419},{1488,0.15592},{1494,0.11718},{1527,0.09192},{1537,0.07757},
{1590,0.04546},{1594,0.04563},{1654,0.03229},{1737,0.01976},{1740,0.01949}};

nlm=NonlinearModelFit[data,{Exp[-a*tt^n*Exp[-(ea/(r*tt))]*t],
(*Constrained parameters*)
10^12<a<10^14,27*10^4<ea<32*10^4,0<n<0.9
},
{
(*Starting values for constrained parameters*)
{a,10^14},{n,0},{ea,30*10^4}
},
tt,Method->"NMinimize"]//Normal

Module[{ttrange=data[[All,1]]},
ttmin=Min[ttrange];
ttmax=Max[ttrange];
];

Show[{
Plot[nlm,{tt,ttmin,ttmax},PlotStyle->{Red,Thick}],
ListPlot[data,PlotStyle->Directive[PointSize[Medium],Blue]]},Axes->False,Frame->True]
```

> $e^{-1.37091\times 10^{10} e^{-33078.6/\text{tt}} \text{tt}^{0.0317634}}$

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I have no time now to do the right job with Log Log data so let me only show straightforward approach.

I don't know how to put constraints on parameters but you can always give starting value.

```
sol = With[{r = 8.31, t = 0.002},
           NonlinearModelFit[
                             mydata,
                             Exp[-(a*tt^n*Exp[-ea/(r*tt)])*t],
                             {{a, 10^13}, {ea, 295000}, {n, 1}},
                             tt
                            ]
          ];
```

> ```
> NonlinearModelFit::cvmit: Failed to converge to the requested accuracy or 
> precision within 100 iterations
> ```

The warning is because it is always hard to fit parameters which differ with order of magnitute so much. But let's see the results:

```
Plot[Normal@sol, {tt, 1200, 1700}, Epilog -> Point@mydata, 
     Axes -> False, Frame -> True, BaseStyle -> AbsolutePointSize@7]
```

[image]